# Java repaint() method doesn't work when I try to delete shapes from panel

Tags: java, object, methods, repaint

I would like to draw some circles every second and delete them all (or at least one) from the panel.

Here is the exisiting code:

```
    public class DrawShape {
        ShapePanel panel;
        public DrawShape(ShapePanel panel) {
            this.panel = panel;

            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int secondsToRun = 3;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > secondsToRun * 1000) {
                        panel.deleteCircle();
                        System.out.println("\t" + panel.circles.size());
                        cancel();
                    } else {
                        panel.addCircle(new Circle((int) (Math.random() * 200), (int) (Math.random() * 200)));
                        System.out.println(panel.circles.size());
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
```

If the time is greater than 3 seconds, delete all circles, else continue to draw circles on screen.

Here is the **ShapePanel** class:

```
    public class ShapePanel extends JPanel {

        public List<Circle> circles = new LinkedList<Circle>();

        public ShapePanel() {

            // Setting up the frame
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBackground(Color.black);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(this); // adding the panel to the frame
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            circles.add(circle);
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void deleteCircle() {
    //        circles.remove(circles.get(0));
            circles.clear(); //remove them all
            this.repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for (Circle c : circles) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawOval(c.x, c.y, Circle.radius * 2, Circle.radius * 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call deleteCircle(), the circles should be removed from the list and repaint. I should end up with a blank screen with no circles in it. I think repaint doesn't work in this case.

**P.S.: first time asking a question, so sorry if it's long one :D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, two things jump out at me immediately.

1. Using `java.util.Timer`

Swing is NOT thread safe and since `java.util.Timer` runs in it's own thread, updating the UI (or in this case, something the UI relies on) could cause you random issues.

I'd consider using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead, as it is triggered inside the Event Dispatching Queue (and is generally simpler to use)

2. Not calling `super.paint`

You've failed to take into consideration what `paint` does and failed to take over it's responsibilities, which, in this case, would be to "prepare" the `Graphics` context for painting.

`Graphics` is a shared resource, which is passed to all the components been updated in the paint pass.  This means it will contain what ever was previously painted to it.

Two recommendations:

1. As a general recommendation, prefer overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint` (`paint` does a lot of important jobs, so unless you're willing to do them, it's generally to high up in the paint chain)
2. Call `super.paintComponent` first, before doing any custom painting.

I would, highly, recommend reading:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

and

- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I used super.paintComponent and it worked, even though my background color was changed (I think it can be fixed somehow). The thing is that today I started with java graphics (I have an app to submit to school) and I stayed like 10-11h, and I'm still staying trying to do research, tutorials and other. I will take a close look at what you sent. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Make sure you only call `super.paintComponent` from within `paintComponent`, don't do this from within `paint` - you bypass a lot fo critical functionality

Comment: I should see, at first, the differences between them, it seems like they are way different than I thought. Thanks a lot for your help!